# Insert first table into temp table when procedure returns multiple tables in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 2 procedures `proc_Data`, `proc_FetchData`.

I'm calling `proc_Data` from within `proc_FetchData`. `proc_Data` returns 2 tables. I want to insert only the first table into a temp table in my second procedure and use it further.

The problem is I cannot change `proc_Data` in any way as this is a very old procedure used in various parts of our application.

Sample code for reference

```
create procedure proc_Data
As
Begin
    select 'Apples'
    select 'Oranges','Grapes'
end

create procedure proc_FetchData
As
Begin
    create table #temp(Data varchar(30))

    insert into #temp
        exec Test_proc

    select * from #temp
end
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014 - is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think anything in T-SQL can do this. You'd need CLR code. Frankly, it's easier to let client code handle this. [See also](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#CLR). Another, possibly cheaper option is to simply copy the first part of the procedure into a new procedure. If it's very old, I'm guessing it's not actively changing, so the duplicate will stay valid. Repeating code is bad in general, but often unavoidable in T-SQl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert only the first table you can use OPENROWSET.

```
create procedure proc_FetchData
As
Begin    
    declare @userData TABLE(Data NVARCHAR(30))
    INSERT INTO @userData
    SELECT * FROMOPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=[server];Trusted_Connection=yes;','EXEC [database name].dbo.proc_Data')    
select * from @userData
end
```

If you need to access all resultsets you will need to use SQLCLR proc: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/da5328a7-5dab-44b3-b2b1-4a8d6d7798b2/insert-into-table-one-or-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql

Comment: thanks for the reply.but it is throwing an error "SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online."

Comment: you need to enable 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'

Comment: sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO

Comment: This worked.You are a genius. But do you recommend doing this on a production server?

Comment: Here is an article about it:

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ad-hoc-distributed-queries-server-configuration-option

Answer (score 2):

You cant do it that way, you can split your first SP into 2 and call it in your second SP, like,

```
create procedure proc_Data1
As
Begin
    select 'Apples'
end

GO
create procedure proc_Data2
As
Begin
    select 'Oranges','Grapes'
end

GO
ALTER procedure proc_FetchData
As
Begin
    create table #temp(
        Data  varchar(30)
    )
    insert into #temp
    exec proc_Data1

    select * from #temp

end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I can't do that as it being used in many places in my application

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a new input parameter with a default value to your procedure and return different datasets depended on its value.

```
ALTER procedure proc_Data
    @Mode   INT = 0
As
Begin
    IF @Mode = 0 BEGIN
        select 'Apples'
        select 'Oranges','Grapes'
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        select 'Apples'
    END

end

go

ALTER procedure proc_FetchData
As
Begin
    create table #temp(Data varchar(30))

    insert into #temp
        exec proc_Data @Mode = 1

    select * from #temp
end
```

After doing so, you will be able to use your proc_Data in any old queries without changes, whereas its output will be different with different @Mode values if you need.