# SQL: How to insert the result of a stored procedure to a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have a stored procedure that outputs 2 tables. I need to insert those 2 result set in two separate temp tables. I am using

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC [dbo].[SomeSP]
```

but it only catch the first table.

Is there anyone knows how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270843/query-that-returns-multiple-result-sets

Comment: [Another sense of deja vu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48442793/4137916).